# How to use grep or awk to save every line from text file as new file?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, awk

I am a scripting beginner.
What i am trying to do.

I have a text file that looks like this (example):

```
hello
hi there
apple
```

I am trying to make a script that saves every line as a separate new file with the line content as file name.
The name of the files should be as follows (without the .txt extension to the output files):

```
hello 
hi there
apple
```

How can i use grep or awk to save every line from a text file as a new file with the line content as file name (without the .txt extension).
Thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Forget using grep or awk and do it in your shell.

```
    while IFS= read -r line
    do echo "$line" > "$line"
    done < FILE
```

Comment: This script did the job. It's possible that the other script also does the job but this one was first. Thanks a bunch :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you determined to use Grep/Awk?

There is a much easier way to do this:

```
while read f; do echo "$f" > "$f"; done<file.txt
```

Make sure to use quotes, especially for the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop if you use `awk` – `print` (on its own) is equivalent to `print $0`, where `$0` is the full input line, without the trailing `\n`. The following is enough:

```
awk '{print>$0}' file
```